# Multilingual Dictionary Solution C++

Tags: c++, ios, multilingual, language-translation

I need a multilingual dictionary accessible through C++ which is capable of performing the following operation:

inputs: Language of Input Word, Input Word, Language of Output Definition

output: A string definition of the input word in the desired output language (NULL if the word is not found)

Some restrictions: This function needs to be able to run in under 0.5 seconds on an iPhone 6. Therefore, only fast and slim web based solutions or highly optimized local dictionary search  functions are suitable.

I have considered using the Bing Translate API to translate the definition of the word to the desired destination language. However, I have been unable to find a dictionary which will return a definition of a word given the language of the input word. Does such a system exist? If not, how could I go about implementing the system outlined here? Any and all suggestions and information are greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I solved this. I downloaded word lists for all of the supported languages. I checked the word list of the language of the given input word and if the input word existed in this list, I used the bing translate API to get the definition of the input word in the destination language. Otherwise I returned NULL as expected.

Here is a link to an English word list similar to the one I used:
http://www-01.sil.org/linguistics/wordlists/english/wordlist/wordsEn.txt

This Microsoft site contains information about the Bing Translator API costs and how to get started:
https://datamarket.azure.com/dataset/bing/microsofttranslator